# How to add new EventReceiver to exist solution in SharePoint 2013

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2013

I need to add new event receiver to exist SharePoint solution. I created new web feature and updated solution. But I don't see new feature on ManageFeatures page in Site Settings. I found one way: to retract the current solution and deploy the new.

It works, but I don't want to retract current solution in productive environment. Are the ways to deploy event receiver without so cardinal measures?

Comment: in production you use Update-SPSolution cmdlet (powershell) and for new feature you need to Install it manually with Install-SPFeature

Comment: @tinamou, you are right. Key word **manualy** :) Thank you